# Why apache throwing forbidden when directory is in home?

Tags: php, apache2, runtime-error, virtualhost

Apache simply unable to access directory (forbidden 403 error), unable to identify the reason why ?

I have made a vhost as:

created: /etc/apache2/sites-available/dev.testvhost.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/najam/projects/php/testvhost
    ServerName dev.testvhost.com
</VirtualHost>
```

added servername in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       dev.testvhost.com
```

executed command:

```
sudo a2ensite dev.testvhost.com.conf
```

then:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

pointing browser to http://dev.testvhost.com gives 403 forbidden error, while error log shows following on each refresh.

> [Wed Jul 13 16:19:42.277573 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 20067]
>   [client 127.0.0.1:58230] AH01630: client denied by server
>   configuration: /home/najam/projects/php/testvhost/

I am very sure about the issue causing error because "testvhost" folder is in home directory "/home/najam/projects/php/testvhost" and when I  move the folder to /var/www/ it starts working (no forbidden error) (after modify documentroot path accordingly in dev.testvhost.com.conf)

Comment: Keep in mind that the http server process needs to have access to each level inside the configured `DocumentRoot` path. It requires to be able to enter and reach each folder recursively. So check the file system permissions for all those folders.

Comment: I changed the permission to 777 and for testing I only kept single index.php file, but no luck :(

Comment: File system permissions `0x777` are nearly _never_ required and generally a bad idea. Take a look at the group ownership and use that for a more intelligent handling. However the issue here probably is what I wrote above: you have to check _all_ folders recursively inside that path... So `/home`, `/home/najam`, `/home/najam/projects`, `/home/najam/projects/php` and `/home/najam/projects/php/testvhost`.

Comment: User "arkascha" is correct in the comment under the original post, and it worked for me. The apache user needs access to the entire path of folders. The "/home" directory already had 755 permissions, but I gave 750 to "/home/user1" and /home/user1/Documents" and "/home/user1/Documents/html", and it works... I put the "apache" user into the "user1" group, so I only had to give GROUP permissions (not world) to the directories. I probably should move my html directory out of Documents (for more privacy for Documents), but this is my personal dev laptop, not a public facing server, so I should be

Answer (score 9):

Try editing your `dev.testvhost.com.conf` to add the `Require all granted` directive for the directory you want to be accessible

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/najam/projects/php/testvhost
    ServerName dev.testvhost.com

    <Directory "/home/najam/projects/php/testvhost">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This block is controlled by Apache's module `mod_authz_core`. See [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require).

Comment: This answer should be the be marked as answer, it works (Debian 10, June 2020). I was trying to access my Laravel 5 webapp on /home/username/laravel-project but got forbidden, my Apache2 conf was configured to match this path and btw, reloaded with success, but I still got forbidden until I try this trick. Worked like a charm. Cheers mate. upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

Apache using another user account, called daemon/www-data depending on the installation. If you switch to the particular user and try to get inside the directory you mentioned above then it won't be possible due to permission problems.

```
su www-data # switch to the user apache running on
cd /home/najam/projects/php/testvhost
```

It will return an error. So you need to add permissions to the particular directory recursively.

The other problem that `/var/www` configured in your httpd.conf to allow connections inside it by default. As /home is not a subdirectory of /var/www then you need apache like permissions to the directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /home/najam/projects/php/testvhost
 ServerName dev.testvhost.com
 <Directory "/home/najan/projects/php/testvhost">
   Allowoverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted 
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This should do the trick.

If not, then you could exchange the Directory directive inside your httpd.conf to your home directory from /var/www, so it applies it's rules to it. The other solution could be to add www-data your user group.

Comment: You are right about apache2 user permission, my colleague suggested the same, but the fix is not working for me :(